# Edirol UA-101 OSX Mojave Drivers

Tags: audio, mojave, driver

I have an Edirol UA-101 and have recently upgraded to Mojave. I was running of High Sierra which supported the audio interface, however I am struggling to make it compatible with Mojave. Is there a driver that exists or a workaround?

Comment: It looks like it's no longer supported past  macOS 10.9 (Mavericks).  It might be time for a new unit.

Comment: Not sure why this got a -1.  +1 to cancel out.

Comment: @Allan I think you might be right. I mean the drivers worked past Mavericks so guess I had been lucky thus far.

Answer (score 4):

I have disabled SIP (System Integrity Protection) by entering the recovery mode (holding cmd+R on boot) and typing "csrutil disable; reboot" on a terminal.
Then I installed the latest driver available from the Roland website (the ones for Mac OS X 10.9) and after a reboot the UA-101 came back to life.
All of this was done on MacOS Mojave 10.14.2 on a MacBook Pro late 2016.
If you want more info head to http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/

Comment: Thanks very very much mya EDIROL UA-101 is back to life now

Comment: Disabling system integrity doesn't seem a good idea though....

Comment: I had to enable the "High Speed" selector switch on the back, then the red USB led came on on the front. worked perfectly after that. Thanks

Comment: Will the UA-101 still work when re-enabling SIP after installation?