# Edirol UA-101 High Sierra not detected

Tags: audio, high-sierra

I have an Edirol UA-101 worked perfect on windows 10 and on Mac El Capitan.
Now I switched to an Imac 2010 I5 8GB ram with high sierra but the system doesn't see it. How can i install the driver? In the system report i can see the UA-101 Connected on my USB port

Comment: Have you opened Audio MIDI Setup.app? Sometimes you need to configure things there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Edirol UA-101 OSX Mojave Drivers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344832/edirol-ua-101-osx-mojave-drivers) From what I can gather, there are no 64-bit drivers, so Mojave will be the last macOS it will work on.